# Multiple Photos to upload from 3DS?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, animal-crossing-new-leaf

I was able to upload one photo, but how can you upload multiple photos on the same post by Nintendo's i.nintendo.net "3DS Image Share" service? I need tips for it for my AC:NL journals.

Comment: Do you have to upload to a specific service? What I do is take my SD card out and put it in my PC and copy the whole set of files over to do whatever with.

Comment: I'm trying to upload to Tumblr. :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to simply copy the photos off of the SD card; you'll need an SD card reader of some sort, though. Most laptops have them. Turn off the 3DS, remove the SD card from it's slot and plug it into the card reader, then open the card reader from the devices menu in your OS. There's a DCIM folder which has all your pictures; inside of a second folder (mine's called "100NIN03") you'll find the actual pictures, and from there you can simply copy them onto your PC to be uploaded, or upload them directly from the SD card.

Per the comments, note two caveats: One, if you have a large (over 16GB) card it's an SDHC card, which not all (old) card readers support. Test your card reader before you depend on this method.

Additionally, the subfolders appear to be created for every 100 photos you take, after the 100th picture a second folder will be created and the file names for the nth picture in each folder are identical. Don't copy two folders' contents to the same location or you'll overwrite some of the files (your OS will probably prompt you before doing this however.)

Comment: If you have a 16 or 32GB card, then it is SDHC. Not all SD card readers are compatible with it. I have a multi-card reader, but since it isn't SDHC compliant I have to use our digital camera as a card reader for my laptop.

Comment: For some additional info, it seems that you can only hold 100 photos in each subfolder. Like BenBrocka, I have "100NIN03", but once that number hit 100, it  created a new folder called "101NIN03" and restarted the photo numbering from "HNI_0001.JPG" again. Keep this in mind for copy/pasting stuff piecemeal, just in case you may accidentally overwrite pictures with the same file name.

Answer (score 0):

I just used Cubeupload.com to upload multiple images from my 3ds. it claims the start of the page didn't load properly, but all of the files are uploaded, to do multiple images, you just keep clicking on "select images" for each new image until you have all you want, and THEN click the upload button

you might want to make an account and log in on your 3ds so you can go right to your images gallery on the site rather than type out the links on your computer manually reading the text from the 3ds